# Assigning a DataTable to a ComboBox and then making changes

Tags: vb.net, combobox, datatable, datasource

VB2010 I have created a DataTable manually so it does not come from a database. I have assigned it to a combobox and it displays my column of data. If I change the DataTable do I have to re-establish the link?

```
'assign first table
dt = GetFirstTable()
cbo.DataSource = dt
cbo.DisplayMember = "Time"
cbo.ValueMember = "Time"

'print out items in combobox

'assign second table
dt = GetSecondTable()
'cbo.DataSource = dt 'do i have to re-connect here?

'print out items in combobox
```

It seems if I do not re-establish the link I get the same items. I though since the cbo was already linked to the dt variable i didn't need to re-link it each time. Is that how that works or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you assign `cbo.DataSource = dt`, and you then recreate `dt`, `cbo.DataSource` will keep pointing to the old table. This is pure pointer logic working here, same principle applies to all .NET code. It does not mean anything that you are re-using the same variable. You could have instead created `dt2` and used that, behavior would be the same. So yes, if you recreate the `DataTable`, you need to reassign `DataSource` again. However, if you change the original `dt`, i.e. add rows, those will appear, so you will not need to reassign `DataSource`. Here is a code sample, to illustrate the approach:

```
Dim _dt As DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  _dt = New DataTable
  With _dt.Columns
    .Add("key")
    .Add("value")
  End With
  With ComboBox1
    .DisplayMember = "value"
    .ValueMember = "key"
    .DataSource = _dt
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  _dt.Rows.Add({"item_key", "item_value"})
End Sub
```

Comment: I see. I think I had a different idea of how the source and table worked. I re-link every time I change the source and its working. thanks.